# Why do we use node* instead of just saying node when initializing a root for the linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, singly-linked-list

Let's say we have these kind of code for the linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
int data;
node* next;
}
```

The code above makes sense as it has a pointer to point out another structure (I suppose it has a recursive existence, correct me if i am wrong).

But, I am struggling with the continuing code:

```
int main (){
node* root;
}
```

Why did we need to put the asterisk when initializing root? The structure root itself already has a pointer that points out the next node.

Comment: `node root;` is fine as well

Comment: For the first (head) node it *might* not matter. It all depends on how you then use it.

Comment: We didn't put it, you did. There are many ways to write code. What you have shown so far is too incomplete to say whether that is the right thing to do or not. Either way can be right depending on what follows.

Comment: just pointing out that the code above won't work, it needs to be struct node inside as well. and then there's the usual typedefs for convenience, etc.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).  And please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: You can do it either way.  In my experience, making `root` a pointer to rather than an instance of `struct node` just makes things a little cleaner.  That way `root` isn’t “special” and doesn’t require different handling then other nodes in the list.

Comment: Detail: "when initializing root" --> `node* root;` _declares_ `root`.  `node* root = NULL;` is an example of _initialization_.

Answer (score 2):

this look like a linked list. Theoritically, you could just do

```
node root;
```

but then the question is : how would you represent an empty linked structure that has nothing in it ? usually, we can use a nullptr (NULL in C) to represent the empty structure. If you build the first node without the pointer, it can't be null. Therefore, your data structure must contain at least one node (unless that's what you want).

Answer (score 2):

For starters this structure declaration (if even do not take into account the forgotten semicolon after the closing brace)

```
struct node {
int data;
node* next;
}
```

is incorrect.

`struct node` and `node` are two different type specifiers. The structure should be declared like

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
```

So the singly-linked list consists of nodes of the same type and each one node points to another next node.

The head or start of the list is specified by a single pointer that denotes the beginning of the list and initially is set to NULL because initially the list is empty.

```
int main( void ){
   node* root = NULL;
}
```

So if each node contains a reference (pointer) to next node then we need to have an initial reference (pointer) to a potentially first node of the list that will be appended to or inserted front of the list.

If this initial reference (pointer) is not equal to NULL then it means that the list has at least one actual node and the reference points to the first node of the list.

Usually the node is incorporated in a structure that denotes a list. For example

```
struct SinglyLinkedList
{
    struct node *head;
};
```

and in main an object of the structure is declared like

```
int main( void )
{
    SinglyLinkedList list = { NULL );
    //…
}
```

The user of the list should not deal directly with objects of the type struct node.

For example a function that pushes front a new node can look like

```
int push_front( struct SinglyLinkedList *list, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = list->head;
        list->head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct SinglyLinkedList
{
    struct node *head;
};

int push_front( struct SinglyLinkedList *list, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = list->head;
        list->head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct SinglyLinkedList list = { NULL };

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( &list, i );
    }

        //…

    return 0;
}
```